# Forward IPsec tunnel from IPv4 endpoint to IPv6 endpoint

Tags: networking, vpn, ipv6, ipsec, socat

I have a new ISP and only have a Dual Stack - lite connection now. That means I can't access my router via IPv4 anymore, since the external IPv4 address is private. I have native IPv6 connectivity.

My IPSec tunnel cannot work on IPv4 only networks (the majority of them).

I have a root server with both IPv4/v6 connectivity. Can I use this server to forward IPSec packets? If so, how? I tried using socat but my iPhone just kept saying it can't reach the VPN endpoint. The commands I tried (parallel) was:

```
socat UDP4-LISTEN:500,fork,su=nobody UDP6:fqdn:500
socat UDP4-LISTEN:4500,fork,su=nobody UDP6:fqdn:4500
socat IP-RECVFROM:50,fork,su=nobody IP6-SENDTO:fqdn:50
```

Comment: You should be able to build a IPv6 tunnel this then transports your IPv4 packets to the server. (Of course the server must then do a IPv4 NAT for these packets)
But I think socat can't do this, you would need something more powerfull for this